# C3P0 Throws Exception in case of @transactional

Tags: hibernate, jpa, c3p0, spring-transactions, transactional

Hi I am using `Hibernate core 4.3.1 FINAL`, `hibernate-c3p0 4.3.1 FINAL`. Using JPA persistence configuration which is as below.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="somename">
    <description>

    </description>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somename?autoReconnect=true" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin" />

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

I am using `JpaTransactionManager` by Spring like this.

In my service class I have used.

```
@Transactional
public void deleteSomething (){...}
```

So, whenever this method, or any method with transaction is executed, I get the following exception:

```
2015-03-01 02:34:16 [DEBUG] - delete from badoc where baId=? and docId=?
Hibernate: delete from badoc where baId=? and docId=?
2015-03-01 02:34:16 [DEBUG] - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager@4b969e3c.acquireResource() returning. 
2015-03-01 02:34:16 [DEBUG] - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@40873594 [managed: 2, unused: 1, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@6f5a9e8e)
2015-03-01 02:34:16 [DEBUG] - decremented pending_acquires: 0
2015-03-01 02:34:16 [DEBUG] - Acquisition series terminated successfully. Decremented pending_acquires [0],  attempts_remaining: 30
2015-03-01 02:34:16 [DEBUG] - Converting Throwable to SQLException...
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.maybeDirtyTransaction(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:2520)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.getMaxRows(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1403)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.close(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:530)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.release(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:407)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.releaseStatements(AbstractBatchImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3400)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3624)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1218)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:515)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.pwc.atlas.service.DocumentService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b0e32825.manageBADocument(<generated>)
    at com.pwc.atlas.rest.SolrController.manageBaDocuments(SolrController.java:463)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2015-03-01 02:34:16 [DEBUG] - Exception clearing maxRows/queryTimeout [You can't operate on a closed Statement!!!]
2015-03-01 02:34:16 [DEBUG] - committed JDBC Connection
2015-03-01 02:34:16 [DEBUG] - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@1295e6d1] after transaction
2015-03-01 02:34:16 [DEBUG] - Closing JPA EntityManager
2015-03-01 02:34:16 [DEBUG] - HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
2015-03-01 02:34:16 [DEBUG] - Releasing JDBC connection
```

The transaction completes but with this exception.

I am pretty new to using JPA with hibernate with connection pooling. Could you please help if I am missing something in the configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the Exception you've logged is shown at DEBUG level only. c3p0 logs things verbosely at DEBUG level.

In this case you've logged a rootCause Exception while it is getting wrapped by an SQLException, which Hibernate then handles. The rootCause shown indicates that the Statement has already been close()ed. The handling of the wrapped Exception is logged with a more informative message:

```
Exception clearing maxRows/queryTimeout [You can't operate on a closed Statement!!!]
```

Hibernate is trying to do some kind of cleanup on a Statement and finding that the Statement is already close()ed. If you Google on "Exception clearing maxRows/queryTimeout", you will find quite a bit on this issue. Possible causes include an application holding onto stale Connections and Connection getting timed out at the server (See a discussion [here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/34). That's against HikariCP. You'll find similar [reports against DBCP](https://6by9.wordpress.com/2009/06/18/tomcatjetty-dbcp-and-stale-connections/) as well.)

Do make sure that there's nothing in your application that holds on to Connections or Sessions which are closed.

You might use [a more reliable Connection testing scheme](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing). In particular, I would start by setting `hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery` to `SELECT 1` and `hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout` to true (and setting `hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period` to 0, eliminating tests while idle for now).

You might also consider upgrading to c3p0-0.9.5, which offers lots of fixes and improvements. (You'll have to override the default transitive dependency in hibernate-c3p0 4.3.1.) But that probably won't resolve this issue.

Comment: Oh, unrelated, but please don't use an `acquireIncrement` of 1. Why not stick with c3p0's default of 3, or even higher? If you can afford for your pool to grow to 100 Connections, you can afford it growing 3 at a time, and client-perceived performance during periods of pool growth will improve.

Comment: Thanks @Steve. I upgraded to hibernate-c3p0 4.3.7 FINAL version. which worked . I am not seeing that exception now.  And thanks for the suggestion to increase the aquireIncrement to 3. I shall do so.